# Using Facebook to register new User on Android App

Tags: android, facebook

At present I have my android app set up so that the user can log in to the app via facebook.  However, I want to be able to give the user an option to register with facebook also, however, there doesn't seem to be any docs on this.  I have trawled through the net and I can't find anything.

Does anyone know how I could implement this or even send me on the right path?  Please don't link me to the fb developer app as I can't find anything on that in relation to this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To register user via Facebook you should follow next steps:

1. Login to facebook.
2. Get credentials you need (id, name, email, date of birth, etc.)
3. Send them to server and create account on server side.

Hope it helped.

Comment: what about password? , i can send id name email but what about password

Comment: How can I distinguish between login and registration?

Comment: Swap-IOS-Android after gaining some experience in this and twitter since as Navigator said get id, name etc.  For your app password, if you create a hash of your id so at registration time, when the user authenticates facebook or twitter add their userid to your server as their userid for your app and then hash their userid and send it to server as your app password